# Can i use user defined functions to process data being added to arangodb

Tags: arangodb

The schema for what i want to be pushing to push to arangodb is this:
{
name,
image
}

this image is a url to an image. Is there any way to automatically process this url and convert it to base64 before pushing to the document to collection?. There are lots of npm packages just for this.

Comment: Have you had a look at Foxx Microservices within ArangoDB? It sounds like a perfect match, it can really help you here. With Foxx you can expose REST API endpoints that your customers consume, and in there it can do all your data validation and manipulation before it actually commits to the DB.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks checking it out